# When do you feel its time to take your chips and go home?

Tags: strategy

When do you feel its time to take your chips and go home? We should identify when we are playing bad but what about chip size? I made $615 in 45 minutes 2 nights ago on 2/3 live in Sydney Australia.  I was happy with the amount and took the chips. but later I wondered what if I stayed longer.

Also does anyone change seats because of cold cards? I change seats for position and view but not cold cards. Is it mathematically viable to change seats or wait it out. Possibly change tables?

Answer (score 2):

There can be a few approaches that people use when deciding when to pack up and leave. Like yourself people get to a certain amount won and are happy and leave. For me personally I'll stop when I no longer feel I have an edge over the table, I feel tired, the game is slowing down/breaking or when I no longer feel I am playing the best I can play. I think its more important to focus on how well you are playing rather than your stack size.

With regards to changing seats due to cold cards, seems very superstitious to me, I'd agree with you to change seat for a better position or on a better softer table. Probability doesn't care if you change seats, you get two cards, the seat doesn't dictate that. Some times you're card dead, just part of the game.